# ¿Porque JWTAuth no aceptar Barer en el token, laravel?

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

actualmente tengo una autorización mediante token con la libreria JWTAuth, este me genera el token correctamente cuando mis credenciales son correctas.

El problema me surge cuando intento enviar el token desde AngularJS, el metodo lo realizo de la siguiente forma:

```
var config = {
                'Authorization': token,
            };
        console.log(config);
        $http.get(server+'ws/usuarios',config).success(function(datas){

            $scope.datas = datas.records;
});
```

Cuando pruebo enviar el token mediante postman me funciona bien:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero en la consola del navegador realiza el envio del token en el encabezado de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

le agrega la palabra Bearer, al realizar la prueba desde postman anteponiendo la palabra bearer efectivamente no devuelve nada, es decir muestra el mensaje que el token no es correcto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por favor como puedo quitar la palabra Bearer o que otra solucion, soy nuevo en este tema de envio de tokens.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿La palabra Bearer aparece cuando haces el console.log(config);? Es decir, Bearer está dentro de la variable token o se añade después?

Comment: Se añade después, cuando realizo el console.log(config) unicamente es el token: "eyJ0eXA...."

Comment: ¿En algún sitio tienes definida una variable como esta: $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + response.token;?

Comment: no, para nada. En que parte del controlador debería ir ?